# In Mongodb Javascript, How To Get 5 Item Random From Collection? Minimal 5 and Maximal 5

Tags: javascript, mongodb

How To Get 5 Item Random From Collection In MongoDb.
Here so far i have do :

```
var playerData = Spark.runtimeCollection("playerNewspaper"); // get the collection data
var currentPlayer = playerData.find().limit(5).skip(Math.random() * playerData.count());

Spark.setScriptData("player_Newspaper", currentPlayer); // return the player via script-data
```

But at the code above it is not perfect generate 5 random Item.

Example :

We Have 10 Record and Want To Get 5 Record Randomly:

When Random Start Record From 7 Then All We can get is only 4 Record Because it start from 7 ( 10 records - 6 = 4 records). But I need if the record we want to get (5 records) is less than it then do random again. So finally we always got minimal 5 records and maximal 5 records.

How to do it ?

Thanks

Dennis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

> var currentPlayer = [ ]; 
>  do { 
>      currentPlayer = playerData.find().limit(5).skip(Math.random() * playerData.count()); 
>  }
>  while (currentPlayer.length< 5);

'do' content will run the first time and checks for 'while' condition. If the length of the array is less than 5 it would re-run the 'do' content. It will go till currentPlayer length is equal to 5.

I assume that  other content is correct and working

Answer (score 0):

I have my own solution too.
Below :

```
var playerData = Spark.runtimeCollection("playerNewspaper"); // get the collection data
var totaldata = playerData.count();
var lim;
if(totaldata <= 50) {
    lim = totaldata;
    var currentPlayer = playerData.find().limit(lim);
} else {
    lim = 50;
    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * playerData.count());

    while((playerData.count() - rnd) < lim) {
        rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * playerData.count());

    }
    var currentPlayer = playerData.find().limit(lim).skip(rnd);
}
```

**But that's for limit 50.**